# Camera not working in WebView Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms app where I am opening a WebView and setting the Source URL.  That site allows users to take pictures of assets etc...  In Chrome (on the Android device), this works fine.  In iOS I'm using a custom renderer to force the use of WKWebView, this works fine.  But this is not working on Android using WebView.  I'm using the out of the box WebView with no custom renderers.  The XF app already uses the camera elsewhere so I know it's not a permissions issue.

Looking at the WebView code from Xamarin, the default WebView renderer enables Javascript and DomStorage and the WebChromeClient is set.

How can I allow camera use from a website within a WebView?

Comment: I'm afraid an answer is not that simple. I have implemented this before and it is a royal pain to do this. Especially when you want to support older Android versions. I did a blogpost on it back then which can get you started, hopefully it helps you a bit: https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/building-a-hybrid-app-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Your solution works well. Thank you!

Comment: Thats good to hear! Good luck :)