# Accessing Camera through Xamarin Forms WebView

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I want to start, and not just access, the native camera application of Android and iOS devices through my ASP.NET Website. This Website will be loaded in a Xamarin WebView. It's already able to access images stored in the gallery of the phone, but i want to take the photo while using the app and don't want to switch apps. This photo should then be loaded onto the website.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217074/camera-not-working-in-webview-xamarin-forms-android

Comment: You can try to bind your js method in your webView to the native method . Then trigger the native method to use the camera feature through calling the corresponding js method.